# "Strange" prime number"  

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let p = a_1a_2.. a_n be a prime number.

Definition: p is "Strange" if p remains prime after deletion of any a_i.

Example 1: 731. If you delete 7 => 31 (prime), if you delete 3 => 71 (prime) 
if you delete 1 => 73 (prime).

Example 2: 3071. If you delete 3 => 71 (prime), if you delete 0 => 371 (prime) 
if you delete 7 => 301 (prime), if you delete 1 => 307 (prime).

Question: Are there infinitely may strange prime?

Please tell me anything.

Pierre MATSUMI

Comment: 17*43 == 731 is NOT a prime!!

Comment: This looks like spam to me, because very of the numbers mentioned are prime (they just look primy, but are not!) --- please clarify

Comment: Even if the numbers were prime, this is more recreational mathematics than research.

Answer (score 7):

This is Sloane's [A051362](https://oeis.org/A051362).  I expect it has only finitely many members, but I don't know of a proof.

[One of the most popular math.se questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/33094/1778) addresses this precise question.

Comment: Nice link with impressive answers.

Comment: I am Pierre. 
Thanks for answers. 

It seems only finitely many possibilities for such strange numbers... 

When I checked in Wikepedia, super-prime is defined to be a prime 
sitting in prime order position from the beginning.

Is it really called super-prime or my denomination 
"strange prime" should be better?




Comment: @pierre: I agree that "super-prime" isn't a good term for these.  If you need to give them a name "strange prime" is fine, but I prefer to describe them than to name them arbitrarily: "Primes which remain prime after deleting any single decimal digit".  If you're writing a paper I'd give the set a variable (S or whatever) and use that.